# SSIS package gets failed due to huge record via linked server connection

Tags: ssis

We have 2 servers, Server01 and Server02.
Scheduler for executing the SSIS package has been created in Server01. We are retrieving some tables from Server02 to Server01 via linked server. And those tables were created as views in Server01.

One table from server02 to server01 has approximately 43 million records. We are using this view in our script in Execute SQL task, it gets automatically failed with below error message, while manual execution or via scheduler.

> Error Message:
>
> OLEDB provided "linked server name" for linked server "server name" returned message "Protocal error in TDS stream.
>
> OLEDB provided "linked server name" for linked server "server name" returned message "Communication link failure"
>
> Physical connection is not usable (0xffffff)
> Semaphore timeout period has expired

Comment: Is there a reason you use a linked server to access server02 instead of creating a connection manager within SSIS to connect directly to server02?

Comment: To confirm, the remote server is also a SQL Server instance or is it a different resource? If SQL Server, what account & authentication method are being used to establish that connection? If the select statement were issued directly against the source, how long would it take to generate that result set?

Comment: Yes, Server02 is highly confidential server and even we didn't have permission to view the table structure.One think I want you to let you know, Sometimes packages will execute while doing manual run, sometimes it won't. It will display "Communication Link failure" error.

Comment: Server02 is not an instance, its an different server. We are having window authentication account.